# Do modern personality traits exist with native people

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality, evolution

I am wondering if there is any evidence of personality traits like intro versus extroversion existing in native people without any contact with modern society, or if they are a result of modern life.

Comment: You might be hard pressed to find 'evidence' studying uncontacted tribes' personality traits. They're called uncontacted for a reason.

Comment: Also I am finding it hard to follow as to why you are trying to find evidence of basic personality traits like introversion vs extroversion with indigenous tribals? There are models of personality traits with farm animals https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6031753/ or lab rats even. It is a very long shot to argue it is a modern western thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the study below conducted on Tsimane (indigenous Bolivians). It uses Big-5 traits to assess whether if a general factor of personality can be identified with the natives (who mostly fit your criteria) similar to western population studies.

Which is 'evidence' that personality traits exists in indigenous tribes the same way they do in Western populations, since well, how else would they measure it?

*van der Linden, Dimitri et al. “How Universal Is the General Factor of Personality? An Analysis of the Big Five in Forager Farmers of the Bolivian Amazon.” Journal of cross-cultural psychology vol. 49,7 (2018): 1081-1097. doi:10.1177/0022022118774925*

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6047301/

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites. The link may change or become unreachable in the future, and without a summary of what the link contains this answer would be useless. Please summarize what is in the link (**don't** just copy and paste) and use the link solely for reference. If you remove the link and the answer cannot stand on its own, it is not a good answer.